# Cannot close SSH connection in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in python so I may have messed up some things.
I am connecting to MySql but after doing the select I want to exit the connection, I tried using `server.stop()` but that did not work.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import getpass
import mysql.connector


#password_ssh = getpass.getpass("Insert Password of SSH Connection")
#password_db = input("Insert Password of MySql DB")
user_ssh = 'user'

user_db = 'user'

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('{host}', port),
        ssh_password= '',
        ssh_username= user_ssh,
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server:
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
        user=user_db, passwd='',
        db='db_name', host='127.0.0.1',
        port=server.local_bind_port)
    mycursor = con.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SELECT.... ")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    server.stop()
print(myresult)
```

I am not able to print the value of the variable: myresult, the variable is not null and if I put it inside the 'with SSH..' it prints, but if I put it outside it does not work.
Am I missing somethings or the indentation is not correct ?

Thank you

Comment: You will have to disconnect the MySQL client connection.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you !! it worked

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your client is still open.

It will allow you to stop server, once you closed your client.

```
con.close()

server.stop()
```